# SOAP-call through SSL using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, ssl, frameworks

I've been supplied a .wsdl-URI and a Java-example (see below) and need to make SOAP-calls through SSL and process the response. I'm using PHP and the Zend Framework, but can't figure out where to get started. I've made calls to SOAP-services earlier using C#.NET, but that only required 2-3 lines of code after configuring the service through a wizard. Is there a simple way to make this call and process the resulting XML ? If not, where can I find a good example to get me started ?

```
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFault;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

public class RegistryDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID= 1L;
    private static final String SERVICE = "https://ServiceProvider.com/TheService.pl";
    private static final String TAG_GETPRODUCT = "getDetails";
    private static String namespaceService = "http://ServiceProvider.com/TheService.xsd";
    private static String namespaceUserSession = "http://ServiceProvider.com/UserSession.xsd";
    private static String SYSTEM = "thesystem";
    private static String USERNAME = "theusername";
    private static String PASSWORD = "thepassword";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            //Create the connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection connection = soapConnFactory.createConnection();

            //Create the actual message
            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();

            MimeHeaders mimeHeader = message.getMimeHeaders();
            mimeHeader.addHeader("SOAPAction", "");

            //Create objects for the message parts            
            SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

            SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
            SOAPElement userSession = header.addChildElement("UserSession", "UserSession", namespaceUserSession);

            userSession.addChildElement("TypeOfService").addTextNode("Integrated");
            userSession.addChildElement("System").addTextNode(SYSTEM);
            userSession.addChildElement("Username").addTextNode(USERNAME);
            userSession.addChildElement("Password").addTextNode(PASSWORD);

            SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

            //Populate the body
            //Create the main element and namespace
            SOAPElement getDetails = body.addChildElement(TAG_GETPRODUCT, "dfg", namespaceService);

            getDetails.addChildElement("queryField1").addTextNode("xxx"); 
            getDetails.addChildElement("queryField2").addTextNode("yyy"); 
            getDetails.addChildElement("queryField3").addTextNode("zzz");  

            //Save the message
            message.saveChanges();

            //Check the input
            System.out.println("\nREQUEST:\n");
            message.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println();

            //Send the message and get a reply   

            //Send the message
            SOAPMessage reply = connection.call(message, SERVICE);

            System.out.println("\nRESPONSE:\n");
            reply.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println();

            {
                SOAPBody retbody = reply.getSOAPBody();
                if (retbody.hasFault()) {
                    SOAPFault fault = retbody.getFault();
                    System.out.println("SOAPfault: " + fault.getFaultString());
                }
                else {
                    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
                    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
                    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("*/RESULT/HOV/ReturnField1");
                    String returnField1 = (String)expr.evaluate(retbody, XPathConstants.STRING);
                    System.out.println("Result: " + returnField1);
                }
            }

            //Close the connection            
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, post PHP code examples of your tries and the output...

Comment: I've tried nothing since I'm not sure where to start. As Tim has commented there are some documentation as zend.com, but nothing that applies to what I'm doing. How to I send named parameters into the SOAP function call? How to I add different nodes like the Java-example does? I would write a simple 3-line-thing based on the example just to show that I've tried, but I'm not sure how much value that has to this discussion. I mean.. the Java-examples doesn't even use a WSDL-file anywhere.

Comment: `Zend_Soap_Client` extends the generic PHP `SoapClient` take a look at its documentation http://us3.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: Ah, finally - that actually answered some questions. It shows how to send inn multiple named parameters, but I still have one question left unanswered: the example shows that the information is separated into two different XML-noded (UserSession and GetDetails). Does the WSDL-file / SOAP-function handle this automatically or should I handle this myself by somehow (ie. sending two different SOAP-requests or calling two functions in the same request or something like that) ?

Answer (score 0):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html - pass in your WSDL URL and then you can make calls as required.

Comment: I've been through the documentation on zend.com without finding anything I can relate to what I'm trying to accomplish. How can I send in parameters ? How can I specify information for the different parts (userSession and getDetails) ? Does the WSDL handle any of this ?

Comment: The Java example is not very clear - do you have any other docs for the web service itself?

Comment: I have some more documentation, but I can't share it without rewriting the content due to confidentiality contracts with the service provider. I'll try to do this some time tomorrow, but until then: does anyone have a concrete example of how to call a SOAP service with multiple parameters and extract a couple of the return XML-nodes into PHP variables? I think that if I just understand how SOAP calls are made and responses processed I can get started testing and perhaps figure the rest of it out myself..